# Java Custom tag containing generated JSTL : not interpreted

Tags: java, jsp, tags

I have a custom tag that has no body at all. I'm trying to programmatically replace the empty body with, for simplicity's sake,

```
[<c:out value="SUCCESS!"/>]
```

The goal is to see "[SUCCESS!]" displayed by the JSP which uses the tag, but all I see is "[]" and if I look at the generated source code, I can see that the c:out statement is written on the page between the brackets, but not interpreted.

Is there a common way to achieve this ? The final goal will be to use other custom tags instead of the "c:out" tag. The tags/content will come from a database.
I tried different techniques with SimpleTagSupport and BodyTagSupport but none of those were successfull. In fact I'm not sure if it is technically possible to do it, since, the tag has already been interpreted at that time.. But then how should this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Server tags (like your custom tag or JSTL tags) get transformed to Java code when [the JSP is translated into a servlet](http://www.jsptutorial.net/understanding-jsp-life-cycle.aspx). For example, the following JSP code:

```
<c:out value="FooBar" />
```

gets translated to something like this inside the servlet:

```
....
OutTag outTag = (OutTag) tagHandlerPool.get(OutTag.class);
outTag.setPageContext(pageContext);
outTag.setParent(null);
outTag.setValue(new String("FooBar"));
int evalOut = outTag.doStartTag();
....
```

In your custom tags you can call other Java classes/methods and can write HTML code (not JSP code) to the response.

The `[<c:out value="SUCCESS!"/>]` is not interpreted because at this level it's just a string that gets written directly to the response.